# Conditional in makefile that redefines variable?

Tags: bash, unix, build, makefile, sh

I have a variable in my makefile I would like to either `unset` or redefine, so that targets `a`, `b` and `c` use the correct value of `MY_VARIABLE` (or none at all) within their respective makefiles.

If I run `make foo` with the following:

```
export MY_VARIABLE := 'false'
foo: prep_foo dist
prep_foo:
    $(shell export MY_VARIABLE='true')
    echo ${MY_VARIABLE}
dist: a b c
a: 
    make -C a/src
b: 
    make -C b/src
c: 
    make -C c/src
```

I get this output:

```
export MY_VARIABLE='true'
echo 'false'
false
...
```

If, instead, I run `make foo` with the following makefile:

```
export MY_VARIABLE := 'false'
foo: prep_foo dist
prep_foo:
    $(shell unset MY_VARIABLE)
    echo ${MY_VARIABLE}
dist: a b c
a: 
    make -C a/src
b: 
    make -C b/src
c: 
    make -C c/src
```

I get the following output:

```
make: unset: No such file or directory
echo 'false'
false
...
```

How can I unset or redefine `MY_VARIABLE` when specifying a target (like `foo`, in this case)?

**EDIT**

Here is the situation I would like to avoid:

```
dist: a b c 
foo: a_foo b_foo c_foo
a:
    make -C a/src
...
a_foo
    make -C a_foo/src
```

I just want the `a` target to use a different value for my particular variable, so that compilation is handled differently in that target's makefile.

Also, it doesn't look like I can `export` or `unset` variables within a target. For example:

```
dist: a b c 
foo: a_foo b_foo c_foo
a:
    make -C a/src
...
a_foo:
    export MY_VARIABLE='true'; make -C a/src
```

If I try to do so, I get something similar to the following error on the `export MY_VARIABLE='true'` line (and similarly if I try to use `unset`):

```
Makefile:16: *** unterminated variable reference.  Stop.
```

Does this help clarify what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT 2**

I tried a target which `touch`-es a file and tries to run the child target's `makefile` (which checks for the file's existence):

```
foo: prep_foo
prep_foo:
    touch a/src/.foo
    make -C a/src
```

When I try to run this via `make foo`, I get the following error:

```
Makefile:14: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

If I remove the `make` statement from `prep_foo`, then I can `touch` the file without getting the error message, but I cannot trigger making the `a` target, so this doesn't seem to help.

The following yields the same `commands commence before first target` error message:

```
foo: prep_foo a
prep_foo:
    touch a/src/.foo
```

Is there an example of using `touch` to communicate state to child targets?

Comment: Commands in different targets can't affect one another. You can't even guarantee the order of targets (e.g. in your case `make -j` will try to run all the targets at once). You can't make `a`, `b` or `c` make differently depending on whether you were trying to `make foo` or just `make dist`.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant to my question. I just want all children targets to conditionally use a different value for a specific variable, when I call a parent target. I don't really care about the order in which children targets are evaluated within a parent target. Does this help clarify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to communicate between targets in a Makefile is through files. Just `touch` a file in one target and check it in the other. Can this help you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I'll edit my question with the error message that results from that approach.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: I cannot replicate your problem. Which line is number 14?

Comment: For brevity, my makefile is different than what I am posting. It's quite long. Do you have a moment to post a working example of using `touch`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that every single shell execution in `make` is done in a new process. Trying to fiddle with the environment variables of recipes like this does not really make much sense -- the environment you have modified in any given line is *gone* after that shell dies, before the next line is executed.

You may be able to do the job like this:

```
a:
    unset MY_VARIABLE; $MAKE -C a/src
```

or

```
a:
    $MAKE MY_VARIABLE=foo -C a/src
```

Comment: I am looking for a clean way of setting variables in one target, and then passing it to other targets. How do I do this without setting custom targets (that is, how do I avoid having to write targets for `a` and `a_foo`, `b` and `b_foo`, etc. to handle each case)?

Comment: Your suggestion does not seem to work. If I put `unset MY_VARIABLE; echo ${MY_VARIABLE}` in `prep_foo`, I still get the old value of `MY_VARIABLE` echo-ed when running `make foo`.

Comment: Oh, damn. I _knew_ I should have tested first, but it seemed so clear... Could you add a sentence or two about the `a` vs `a_foo` targets to the problem description, then I'll delete this answer? That seems too useful to lose -- though I don't exactly understand why you'd have two different ways of building `a`: one via `foo` and one without `foo`. (Could you explain that a bit?)